# indexing github account

Tags: seo, google, search-engines, github

Its been 7 months since i created my github account.
However Google still hasn't indexed my github page.
Does anyone know what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

Two words: quality backlinks.

Bait reputable websites into linking your github projects and/or profile (by having interesting projects). Link to them from other web properties you own that are indexed in google, like your personal website if you have one. And share your github projects publicly on social media.

Even the smallest amount of fanfare should be enough to get a GitHub profile indexed, since the domain is high-profile in google search.

Comment: The issue is not even my portfolio has been indexed yet

Comment: though i have submitted a sitemao for it a day ago

Comment: definitely see the question that stephen linked!

Comment: I solved the issue after I submitted a sitemap for my portfolio. Google then indexed my github page from the link that i had left on my portfolio.